# Is this sentence valid?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> Blair was never a real socialist.
>
> So, he charges a fortune to give talks.

Is this valid and sound, valid and unsound or invalid?

Comment: That is not a question about mathematics.

Comment: Yes it is a question of logic

Comment: And logic is part of mathematics.

Comment: Pretending that your political rant is a "question of logic" does not make it so.

Comment: An *argument* is valid; the purported argument of your question is of the "form" : $p$, therefore $q$. Thus it is not valid.

Comment: It is just the nature of the exercise, it's not intentionally meant to be a  political rant. Thank you @mauro so this inferences is invalid then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, technically no answer can be given, because the argument is incomplete.  To complete it so that *a purely logical analysis* can be given, one would have to fill in definitions and propositions for 'being a real Socialist', and 'charging a fortune to give talks', and probably more.

That said, no, I wouldn't call the argument valid.  Not being a Socialist doesn't imply that Blair MUST charge a fortune.  Blair could donate the time, charge a nominal fee to avoid tax penalties, be fulfilling a contractual obligation, etc.  Also note that charging a fortune doesn't imply Blair isn't a Socialist - it all depends on what Blair does with that fortune afterwards (e.g it could be donated to charity, spread among the people in Blair's neighborhood, etc.).